# prevState in componentDidUpdate is the currentState?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, state

I've used `componentDidUpdate()` in the past and it has worked as expected.

This time, however, I did

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.object.someString !== this.state.object.someString) {
        console.log(true);
    }
}
```

and `true` is never logged. I logged both state objects to the console and found out they are exactly the same one: the current state.

Is this a bug? What am I missing here?

Thank you.

Edit: I tried to do the same thing with `componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState)` and again, they're the same object.

Edit 2: I'm changing the state by doing:

```
modifyObject = (field, value) => {
    const { object } = this.state;
    object[field] = value;
    this.setState({ object });
}
```

Comment: Can you show the rest of the code where the update to the state is triggered? It looks like the state isn't actually updated?

Comment: The state is modified by a change in an object like so:
`modifyObject = (field, value) => {
    const { object } = this.state;
    character[field] = value;
    this.setState({ object });
  }`

Comment: what is `character` and where did it come from? You are not mutating your `object` variable either. By the looks of it, you are just updating the state as it was previously

Comment: componentDidUpdate is not only called when state changes, but also when the parent re-renders or the props change

Comment: Can you show a piece of code which is responsible for your changing state? Seems weird to me.

Comment: My bad on that last comment, I added how I'm changing the state in the question.

Comment: Can you make your code uniform in your question please? I assume that `someString` is meant to be `object[value]` or something? I understand that these are placeholders to simplify the question, and that's great, but it has to make sense :)

Comment: well, you are mutating the current state, so it's not surprising they have the same value, you should probably go for `this.setState({ object: { ...object, [field]: value } })` instead. Though I don't see why your state has to be called object though, there seems to be so much better options for naming ;)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In the added code, you are mutating a reference object by changing just a property on the object. This means that eventually `nextProps` and `previousProps` in essence refer to the same reference.

So it is no surprise that your `componentDidUpdate` didn't find a difference.

What you should do is create a new version of your object, and use that one to set the state, like:

```
this.setState({ object: { ...object, [field]: value } })
```

or if you don't have the spread operator, something like

```
this.setState( { object: Object.assign({}, object, { [field]: value }) } );
```

Answer (score 4):

note that:

**componentDidUpdate() will not be invoked if shouldComponentUpdate() returns false.**
ref: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

```
 shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if (this.state.someString !== nextState.someString) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.someString !== this.state.someString) {
        console.log(true);
    }
}
```

in some cases better use something like lodash isEqual method to deeply compare your state/props when you use `shouldComponentUpdate`:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
        return !isEqual(this.state, nextState);
      }
```

if you have sophisticated props/state this will boost your performance as no wasteful rendering occurs

Comment: His problem was the fact that he was mutating a referenced object on the state, lodash would have returned false exactly the same as his code did

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Icepickle for your comment, which solved the problem.

Instead of doing

```
modifyObject = (field, value) => {
    const { object } = this.state;
    object[field] = value;
    this.setState({ object });
}
```

I did

```
modifyObject = (field, value) => {
    const { object } = this.state;
    this.setState({ object: { ...object, [field]: value } });
}
```

Thanks again.